# Is there any reason not to call data() immediately when fetching data from firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on an existing project and it's my first time working with firestore. In this project, they have several queries that they use to fetch data, but most of them are working different. That results in some data in snapshot form, some data called with `data()` already, some with ids and some without them, etc... Not even talking about the several ways those documents are returned.

I would want to change this and just return a list of documents or a document in all those queries. Not at all snapshots anymore. But I'm wondering: Is there any reason why I shouldn't immediately call `data()` before returning the documents?

PS: I'd include the document ID in the objects too as we need those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no benefit from a cost or technical standpoint to avoid calling the data() method on a DocumentSnapshot.  At the point you've received snapshots you've incurred reads on your database so you won't save money or lower your response time.

The only reason you wouldn't call data() or get() is if you just wanted the document ID or to check if the document exists.

Comment: Basically I want to check the existence of the document when I fetched it immediately and if it exists return it with the id added to the object, otherwise just undefined. In that way I only have the data around the application and we can change database without major changes if that would be needed in the future. I guess I won't need the snapshot anywhere else anymore then?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not really understanding what you're asking or what your goal is.  Whether you call data() or not will not result in any noticeable performance or cost improvements.  If you want to check the existence of a doc you can call the exists() method on the snapshot and if true return {id: snapshot.id, ...snapshot.data()}, otherwise return null.